# XSLT/XPath: how to use xsl:apply-templates on all but specific elements

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following XML code:

```
<detaileddescription>
   <para>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquam
   interdum erat, <computeroutput>monospace output</computeroutput> eget rhoncus nunc
   porttitor ut. Ut ac metus sed erat rutrum dignissim.
   <parameterlist kind="param">
       <parameteritem>
           <parameternamelist>
               <parametername>item1</parametername>
           </parameternamelist>
           <parameterdescription>
               <para>Param description.</para>
           </parameterdescription>
        </parameteritem>
    </parameterlist>
    <simplesect kind="return">
        <para>
            <computeroutput>ERR</computeroutput> mattis nunc sed velit ultricies
            volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus nec ligula blandit urna lobortis   
            tempus.
        </para>
     </simplesect>
     </para>
 </detaileddescription>
```

I'd like to use xsl:apply-templates only to the text node child of the `detaileddescription/para` element and the `<computeroutput>` element that's inside the text node.  In other words, I want to apply-templates only to the following content:

```
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquam
   interdum erat, <computeroutput>monospace output</computeroutput> eget rhoncus nunc
   porttitor ut. Ut ac metus sed erat rutrum dignissim.
```

Can anyone show me how to do this using XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="detaileddescription/para/(text()|computeroutput)"/>
```

of course, depending on the context note. Otherwise, you could also mean the corresponding tempate that will fit only those elements you want:

```
<xsl:template match="detaileddescription/para/(text()|computeroutput)"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="." /> 
  <!-- or whatever you want to do with it -->
</xsl:template>
```

Hope this helps, 
R

Comment: Ruprecht von Waldenfels: it isn't necessary to specify such a long match pattern -- one can use just `<xsl:template match="computeroutput">`

Comment: I managed to get my transformation working using modes and the XPath 2.0 'except' operator, but I think your match expression is much cleaner.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

here is one, although probably not the best way to do it. i baked you a [cake](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/8RQvTR/4)

i created a copy-template, which copies everything and the last two templates are stop-templates, that don't produce any output.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="detaileddescription">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="para"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parameterlist"/>
<xsl:template match="simplesect"/>
```

i edited in the second template: this will remove (or rather not copy) the `<detaileddescription>` tag.

Comment: Thanks @mindandmedia.  That works, of course, but I should have added in my originalpost that I have to process the parameterlist and simplesect elements elsewhere in the stylesheet, so I can't use them as simple 'stop' templates.  Perhaps I could use your technique and add modes to process the other elements.

Comment: that's why I added, probably not the best way, i figured as much... BUT, can't you omit the first template and start the `<xsl:copy>` in the `<detaileddescription>` template? no, wait, maybe two passes?

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*/para[1]/(text()|computeroutput)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="computeroutput">
  <xsl:sequence select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<detaileddescription>
   <para>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquam
   interdum erat, <computeroutput>monospace output</computeroutput> eget rhoncus nunc
   porttitor ut. Ut ac metus sed erat rutrum dignissim.
   <parameterlist kind="param">
       <parameteritem>
           <parameternamelist>
               <parametername>item1</parametername>
           </parameternamelist>
           <parameterdescription>
               <para>Param description.</para>
           </parameterdescription>
        </parameteritem>
    </parameterlist>
    <simplesect kind="return">
        <para>
            <computeroutput>ERR</computeroutput> mattis nunc sed velit ultricies
            volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus nec ligula blandit urna lobortis
            tempus.
        </para>
     </simplesect>
     </para>
 </detaileddescription>
```

**processes (applies templates to) only the wanted nodes and for this demo puposes just copies these nodes to the output**:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquam
   interdum erat, <computeroutput>monospace output</computeroutput> eget rhoncus nunc
   porttitor ut. Ut ac metus sed erat rutrum dignissim.
```